# MySQL using MAX(datetime) and wanting to return an additional column

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I'm using this query

```
SELECT id, MAX(datetime) AS most_recent_sign_event 
FROM ATTENDANCE 
WHERE id = 2 
GROUP BY id;
```

which returns

```
[{"ID":2,"MOST_RECENT_SIGN_EVENT":"2021-08-29T15:17:44.000Z"}]
```

but I also want to return the column 'type' which I can't currently figure out how to do. Everything I try results in a dynamic SQL error.

```
SELECT id, type, MAX(datetime) AS most_recent_sign_event 
FROM ATTENDANCE 
WHERE id = 2 
GROUP BY id;

SELECT id AND type, MAX(datetime) AS most_recent_sign_event 
FROM ATTENDANCE 
WHERE id = 2 
GROUP BY id;
```

etc

thanks for any help!

Comment: Whats a dynamic Sql Error? Do you realise the second query is doing a  `GROUP BY opid;` Does `opid` actually exist

Comment: `SELECT id AND type, ....` is of course invalid syntax

Comment: Is `type` a column in the `ATTENDANCE` table?

Comment: Do a `SHOW CREATE TABLE ATTENDANCE ;` and copy/paste the output to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you didn't show us the table layout, I'm assuming `type` actually IS a column in the `ATTENDANCE` table, and you're not asking us how to return the data type of a column, or something like that.

Your problem might be as simple as this:

in SQL, when you use a `GROUP BY` statement, every column in your result needs to either be

- a call to an aggregate function (such as `MAX()`)
- a column referenced in your group-by clause
- an expression referencing one of the previous two. (There are a few other nuances that are allowed, but that's the general rule.)

So you may just need to do this:

```
SELECT id, type, MAX(datetime) AS most_recent_sign_event 
FROM ATTENDANCE 
WHERE id = 2 
GROUP BY id, type;
```

Comment: Thank you, Ann, that seems to have done the trick! Apols for not showing the layout!

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want the type for the most recent `datetime`.  If so, you can use:

```
select a.*
from attendance a
where id = 2
order by datetime desc
limit 1;
```

In Firebird, you would use:

```
select first 1 a.*
from attendance a
where id = 2
order by datetime desc;
```

Comment: You're so right about me just wanting the most recent datetime...sadly this database is (it turns out, sorry) Firebird, so LIMIT doesn't seem to work. I tried SELECT FIRST but that didn't work either. Thank you though!

Comment: @daneee . . . Firebird uses `select first`.  Your question is tagged MySQL, so you are going to get MySQL answers.  Not Firebird answers.

Comment: Yes. Totally fair enough and my mistake. Thanks